# Why is i equal to -1？

Tags: c++11, visual-c++, c++14

My C++ code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int i = 0;

    cout << (i=0) << endl;

    if(i=0) {
        i=1;
    }

    cout << i;

    return 0;
}
```

Why is `(i=0)` equal to 0?

Comment: It's equal to zero because you need to [read a book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). The problem is assignment versus comparison for equality.

Comment: To be fair this is a novice mistake. We all made such mistakes while we were learning...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude There is no need to be rude on this site. Would you consider redacting the first sentence?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes,I konw.But My question is  that why does "cout<<(i=0);" output "0"?

Comment: @yellowantphil I miss a ";" at the sixth line.It is my fault.But My question is that why does "cout<<(i=0);" output "0"?

Comment: Because `i=0` is ASSIGNING, not comparing. And the value of the assignment expression is the value being assigned.

Comment: @yellowantphil I have read six chapters of a C++ book named "C++ primer".But I doesn't find the answer.

Comment: @FredLarson Your answer is fantastic!Thanks a lot!

Comment: @yellowantphil.I think "if(i=0)" is equivalent to “if(0)”.So "{i = 1;}" is not executed by the program.What is your point of view?

Comment: @DBPriGuy I don't find Someprogrammerdude's comment to be rude, - he even provided a link to a list of good books. The mistake is obviously a novice one and most books cover this issue.

Comment: @lisyarus My specific issue with his comment is that phrase "you need to read a book" is often considered derogatory, at least in American English.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have confused the assignment operator '=' with the equality operator '=='.

Thus, your `if` statement `if(i=0)` isn't *checking* whether i is equal to 0, it is *assigning* 0 to i. And since that assignment succeeded, the `if` succeeded and so i was subsequently assigned to the value in the statement.

EDIT:

As per request: Why does "cout<<(i=0);" put out"0"?

`cout<<(i=0)<<endl;` prints zero because once again, `i=0` is an assignment statement, not a comparison statement. It is not comparing i to 0 then printing the result, it is *assigning* i to 0 and then printing i. Since i is 0, the character '0' gets printed.

Comment: Yes,I konw.But why does "cout<<(i=0);" put out"0"?

Comment: It is not clear that that was your question, but I will add an addendum. You may want to edit your question to add clarity to what specifically you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you put you condition to `if(condition)` statements:

If value returned by condition is != 0, then statements are executed

If value returned by condition is == 0 then statements are not executed.

Assignment operator return the reference to value

So:
If you put assignment operator to if, then the results of the assignment will be checked and i=0 return 0 so the statements won't be executed.

Answer (score -2):

If you put your code on more lines and use a debugger you can answer your own question.

Should be obvious that the body of if(0) never runs.

Comment: Yes,I konw.But why does "cout<<(i=0);" output "0"?

Comment: This is not an answer. Even if it were, it's fairly condescending. Not sure why people do this. -1